# AS3 AIR (ios and android) CameraRoll issue

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air

I've been trying to sort out an issue for a week or so now. Googled to no avail. I'm currently working on an iOS/Android app that has a feature in the game to take a screenshot and have it show up in the mobile device's gallery.

I'm using the CameraRoll object and the issue is that some objects on screen have smoothing applied. However the CameraRoll screenshot ignores this. Which makes the resulting screen shot have some objects with jaggies.

I've found a number of cries for help on the same issue while googling, but no answers.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: hard to help if you dont show your code or image of problem

Comment: not allowed to. Under NDA. However I can show you the line that takes the picture:

[code]
camRoll.addBitmapData(screenShot);
[/code]

camRoll is a CameraRoll object and screenshot is a BitmapData.

edit: I apparently don't know the code tags for this site either : /

Comment: I doubt the code to take a picture is covered by an NDA - and if it is, you have just broken the NDA by talking about it on a public forum.

Comment: Read what is written. I cannot take a picture of the game I'm working on that has not been released yet. Nor can I give out the source code. I like my job and prefer to keep it. Furthermore what does it matter? I've explained exactly the issue. Some objects in the screen shot use smoothing. The smoothing is ignored by the addBitmapData method and therefore results in jaggies in the screenie. How do I overcome that. That is the question. Little to no code nor a screen shot is required to ask this question and get a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jaggies in flash are common since smoothing on bitmaps is disabled by default (more cpu intensive).  I'd recommend creating a new bitmap from the CameraRoll [MediaEvent.SELECT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html#event%3aselect) event.  Inside, it should return `event.data` which is a [MediaPromise object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/MediaPromise.html). Inside that, you should find a read-only [`file`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/MediaPromise.html#file) property where you should be able to find the image.

Then it's just a matter of creating your new image with smoothing.

```
var img:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
img.bitmapData = file.bitmapData;
img.smoothing = true;
addChild(img);
```

I've never tried this on mobile before, but [it's a common issue](http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2009/09/scaling-your-images-in-flash-player-smooth-those-things/) which I believe you're encountering.

---

**Addendum:**

If you're having an issue with the system based screenshot services, you could create your own using pure AS3.  The logic being, AS3 should do a pixel-by-pixel block copy of the stage (thereby respecting the smoothing values of your images).

Try this:

```
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
myBitmapData.draw(stage);
```

Comment: I'm not certain that would work. If I've read your links correctly. The MediaEvent.SELECT event is for the user selecting an existing image from their gallery. Whereas I'm taking a snapshot of the game and placing it into the gallery. Currently I'm passing in a BitmapData which has copied the pixels of the movieclip containing the scene. Some sub movieclips are using smoothing but it's not part of the BitmapData as smoothing is applied when drawing to screen. So the resulting screenshot has only some objects that are jaggy (the ones using smoothing) while others are fine.

Comment: The objects using smoothing would look jaggy in gameplay if they didn't use smoothing.

Perhaps you mean that I essentially make 2 screen shots? The original with jaggies and then using the MediaEvent.SELECT callback to smooth it?...and wouldn't that require the user to pick the image manually?

Comment: Looks like I didn't fully recognize the issue you were dealing with (my bad).  I'd suggest this instead:  when taking a screenshot, keep an array of images that have smoothing applied, and just prior to taking the screenshot, toggle smoothing off.  When the screenshot is taken, re-apply it.  Or, do a manual pixel-copy to create your own screenshot.

Comment: So to bullet point what you're saying:
-keep a list of objects using smoothing (conveniently I already have them in a list for other reasons)
-before screen shot, turn off smoothing on each
-then back on? or on for the whole screen shot?

Also I am already doing a pixel copy to make the screen shot. The reason that didn't work is because smoothing isn't part of the BitmapData.

Comment: Doing a pixel copy of the screen should work if you're pulling the image from the stage, and not the bitmap itself.  At that point, you're dealing with a composted image, not a bitmap's particular values.  Unfortunately, I couldn't say what may fix your issue without more detail.  As this is your first post on StackOverflow, consider creating a succinct example which you can share that exemplifies the issue.  You'll find much better responses that way.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work : / It's too bad adobe didn't have a screen shot library that would take shots with all post effects like smoothing included.